# SQL combine separate queries

Tags: sql

Sorry for the beginner question. But how can I put these queries into one data set rather than multiple queries? They are all being taken out of the same table. Also as you can see there is an "Open_Time" This is a DATE format. How can I write that to say AND open_date is within the last 60 days?

```
SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='Crosby'
AND Severity=4
AND Open_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='Crosby'
AND Severity=5
AND Open_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='Crosby'
AND Severity=4
AND Close_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='Crosby'
AND Severity=4
AND Close_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='EUC'
AND Severity=4
AND Open_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='EUC'
AND Severity=5
AND Open_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='EUC'
AND Severity=4
AND Close_Time<=60;

SELECT COUNT(P_NUMBER)
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment='EUC'
AND Severity=4
AND Close_Time<=60;
```

Comment: use union to have one result set. but i am use there is a better way you can write this SQL!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sql.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Open_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p1,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Open_Time)<=60  THEN P_NUMBER END) as p2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Close_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p3,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Close_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p4,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 4 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Open_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p5,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 5 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Open_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p6,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 4 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Close_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p7,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 5 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Close_Time)<=60 THEN P_NUMBER END) as p8
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE Assignment IN('EUC','Crosby')
AND Severity IN(4,5)
```

Comment: Could I include a close_time within 60 days as well?

Comment: since it is <=60 it will include those too.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity=4 AND Open_Time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number1
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity=5 AND Open_Time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number2
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity=4 AND close_time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number3
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity=5 AND close_time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number4
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity=4 AND Open_Time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number5
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity=5 AND Open_Time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number6
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity=4 AND close_time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number7
,SUM(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity=5 AND close_time<=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P_number8
FROM PROBLEM_REPORT
```

Answer (score 0):

There `WHERE` clause in the query will make the query much faster since it will only calculate on the filtered rows.

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND Open_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND Open_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 4 AND Close_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'Crosby' AND Severity = 5 AND Close_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 4 AND Open_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 5 AND Open_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 4 AND Close_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END),
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignment = 'EUC' AND Severity = 5 AND Close_Time <= 60 THEN P_NUMBER END)
FROM    PROBLEM_REPORT
WHERE   Assignment IN ('Crosby', 'EUC') AND
        Severity IN (4,5) AND
        (Open_Time <= 60 OR Close_Time <= 60)
```

Comment: How would I implement the close_time and Open_time less than 60 days in here?

Comment: what is the datatype of `close_time` and `Open_time`? and by `less than 60 days` you mean what?

Comment: It is a DATE. And I mean if it was closed within the last 60 days

Comment: instead of writing `Open_Time <= 60` try changing it into `DATEDIFF (day, GETDATE(), Open_Time) <= 60` then have some feedback..

Comment: @JW웃 any reason why not to use aggregate functions for this situation?

Comment: @FabianBigler well it depends on what the OP wants, honestly it's not clear and not stated on the question but my query and your query is different. You query produces multiple rows while mine is not. It will transpose the rows into columns.

Comment: @JW웃 Ok. Thanks for your statement. I was just wondering why I got downvotes, since as you pointed out - it is not stated what the OP wants. Nevermind, thank you!

Comment: @FabianBigler by seeing your edit history, the primary answer you have posted will returned invalid result that's why you have been downvoted. Since you have edited your answer and hopefully will be seen by the downvoter, he can reverse the vote. `:)`

Comment: @JW웃 Yeah, I had to be fast.:P Turned out to be wrong though. Thanks mate!

Comment: it worked but is there a way to get the data to come out like

Comment: Crosby   4   100
Crosby   5   200
EUC      4    50
EUC      5    43

Comment: can you post your desired result along with your question? I can't clearly understand it via comment.